# Integrate Magento-1.7.0.2 with Opentaps-1.5

Tags: magento, integration, opentaps

Just a quick one, could anyone help me with the details of how to integrate Magento-1.7.0.2 and Opentaps-1.5. The tutorials on this [link](http://www.opentaps.org/docs/index.php/Opentaps_Magento_Integration) which is on Opentaps Wiki is outdated. It only detailed the integration with earlier versions of Magento, and it seems these versions are no longer in Magento Repo/archive

Answer (score 0):

Hello I am the author of the previous integration of magento into opentaps.   At the moment there is not integration for the 2 as we are not working in magento anymore.  If you like we can help you find the way